# SQL Server 2012: Invoke user defined function in CHECK constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, check-constraint

I've written a function that returns `int`
Still, I can't use it in CHECK constraint, this error is output:

> 'myFunction' is not a recognized built-in function name.

```
create table MyTable(
attr varchar(100) CHECK(myFunction(attr)=1)
);
```

I also tried

```
create table MyTable(
attr varchar(100)
);
alter table MyTable
add constraint CheckAttr
CHECK(myFunction(attr)=1);
```

I saw people wrote that it is not possible to invoke user defined functions in CHECK constraint, but [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213016%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) it's written it is possible:

> CHECK constraints
>
> User-defined functions that return scalar values can be invoked in CHECK constraints if the argument values passed to the function reference columns only in the table or constants. Each time the query processor checks the constraint, query processor calls the function with the argument values associated with the current row being checked. The owner of a table must also be the owner of the user-defined function invoked by a CHECK constraint on the table.

Comment: You have to use the schema, as NoDisplayName has shown. However, I'd also caution that the combination of check constraint and UDF is usually done to try to implement multi-row or multi-table constraints and are easy to get wrong for corner cases - if you could show the actual function and explain what's needed, we may have a better overall suggestion.

Comment: Well, I know it is not generally a good idea, but I was asked to do this: the function checks validity of email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `schema name` when you are calling `scalar function`

```
create table MyTable(
attr varchar(100) CHECK(schema_name.myFunction(attr)=1)
);
```

As mentioned by Damien_The_Unbeliever there are drawbacks in using `UDF` in `check constraint` for more info [check here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/07/01/when-check-constraints-using-udfs-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx)

Comment: /facepalm

Thanks, now that works) I have to wait several more minutes before accepting the answer)