# Create a check constraint that a value exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, check-constraints

I'm using a mariaDB instance and I would like to create a check constraint that a value must exist in another table. In the below example, TableA.Number must already exist in TableB.

### TableA

Name varchar(30)

Number int

### TableB

Number int

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but have you already tried with foreign keys?

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger to achieve the same

```
CREATE TRIGGER Check_exist_in_B BEFORE

INSERT ON TableA >

DECLARE ExistingNum INT;>

SET @ExistingNum : = (
        SELECT NUMBER
        FROM TableB
        WHERE b.number = new.number
        ) >

IF (@ExistingNum IS NULL) THEN > SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' >
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not exists in B' >
    END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293567/sql-server-2012-invoke-user-defined-function-in-check-constraint